# How parse internal array json

Tags: java, json, gson, retrofit

I have json:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "result": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "imgUrl": "http://test.com/image.jpg",
      "title": "image"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "imgUrl": "http://test.com/image2.jpg",
      "title": "image2"
    } 
  ],
  "jsonrpc": "2.0"
}
```

how i can parse internal array, i try default retroif gson parsing using model

```
public class TestRequest {

    public int id;
    public List<ArrayItems> result;
    public String jsonrpc;    
}

public class Item {

   public int id;
   public String imgUrl;
   public String title;
}
```

and i have error: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY.
Then i try hand parse

```
Item[] items = GSON.fromJson(json, Item[].class);
```

and have error:

> Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT.

What do we have to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main problem is you have a `List<Item>` in your *POJO* and you pass `Item[].class` to the parser, what does not match.

```
Item[] items = GSON.fromJson(json, Item[].class);
//                                 ↑ here!!!!
```

---

Anyway, IMHO this is not the right way you should parse this Json.

- You have a json response with a main object containing 3 tags (`id` `result` and `jsonrpc`).
- You created something like a Java POJOs representing this main object (`TestRequest`)

Soooooooo....

## **USE IT!**

According to this, if you parse main object you will have all json content.

```
TestRequest data = gson.fromJson(reader, TestRequest.class);
```

Now, lets test it, to have a friendly output, I override `Item::toString()` in this way:

```
class Item {

    public int id;
    public String imgUrl;
    public String title;
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.id + "-" + this.title;
    }
}
```

And I tested using this `main` method:

```
final String FILE_PATH      = "C:\\tmp\\38830664.json"; // use your own!!!

Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(FILE_PATH));
TestRequest data = gson.fromJson(reader, TestRequest.class);

for (Item i :data.result)
    System.out.println(i);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1-image
2-image2
```